# How to get intellisense for Linux headers on VS2019 (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, wiringpi

I coding a C++ WiringPi (Linux) project using these libraries:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
```

I am on Windows and I'm getting a "'sys/socket.h': No such file or directory"
error. I know Windows doesn't have sys/socket.h, arpa/inet.h etc but if I don't have files I'm getting a lot of unnecessary errors and intellisense isn't working.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Not possible I guess. You need to use Windows specific functions.

Comment: I can't use windows functions because i coding for raspberry os (linux)

Comment: Then you have to use MinGW GCC compiler in order to access those files. But I am not sure if it's possible to integrate MinGW with Visual Studio (may work with Visual Studio Code though).

Comment: @kiner_shah it seems possible: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-mingw-and-cygwin-with-visual-cpp-and-open-folder/

Comment: @DavidRanieri, ohh amazing, that's convenient. :-)

Comment: If you build on remote PC, consider adjusting `copyAdditionalIncludeDirectoriesList` vendor property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-json-reference?view=msvc-160#visual-studio-remote-settings-vendor-map